# How to extract the below text from the html using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the HTML code .. I want to extract like here ...    "Featuring impressive design, Magic Mouse 2 is completely rechargeable, so you'll eliminate the use of traditional batteries. It's lighter, has fewer moving parts thanks to its built-in battery and continuous bottom shell, and has an optimized foot design - all helping Magic Mouse 2 track easier and move with less resistance across your desk. And the multi-touch surface allows you to perform simple gestures such as swiping between web pages and scrolling through documents. Magic Mouse 2 is ready to go right out of the box and pairs automatically with your Mac

Very sensitive item."

```html
<div id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderFull_productInfoTabUC_divOverview">
<p>.text 1</p>
<p>.text 2</p>
<p>.text 3</p>
<p>.text 4</p>
<h6 class="NoBottomMargin"></h6>
"Featuring impressive design, Magic Mouse 2 is completely rechargeable, so you'll eliminate the use of traditional batteries. It's lighter, has fewer moving parts thanks to its built-in battery and continuous bottom shell, and has an optimized foot design - all helping Magic Mouse 2 track easier and move with less resistance across your desk. And the multi-touch surface allows you to perform simple gestures such as swiping between web pages and scrolling through documents. Magic Mouse 2 is ready to go right out of the box and pairs automatically with your Mac."
<br>
Very sensitive item.
<br>
<h6 class="NoBottomMargin">specifivation</h6>
<ul>
<li>Magic is in the multi-touch</li>
<li>One or two, left or right</li>
<li>Laser tracking engine</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't HTML, its just plain text. In HTML, you will need to find a correct HTML element you want and then use `.text()` or `.html()` functions to extract it.

Comment: thank for your reply 
I tried with $("[id$='divOverview'] .NoBottomMargin")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue; but missing the second text (i.e "Very sensitive item." ) after the br tag

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should enclose the text in a `<p>` tag - since it contains text and to ensure that it is picking up only the specific element - I added a class to the p and targetted that using .text() and also you should indent your code for easier readability.

```js
var requiredText = $(".getThisText").text();
console.log(requiredText)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderFull_productInfoTabUC_divOverview">
  <p>.text 1</p>
  <p>.text 2</p>
  <p>.text 3</p>
  <p>.text 4</p>
  <h6 class="NoBottomMargin"></h6>
  <p class="getThisText">"Featuring impressive design, Magic Mouse 2 is completely rechargeable, so you'll eliminate the use of traditional batteries. It's lighter, has fewer moving parts thanks to its built-in battery and continuous bottom shell, and has an optimized foot design - all helping Magic Mouse 2 track easier and move with less resistance across your desk. And the multi-touch surface allows you to perform simple gestures such as swiping between web pages and scrolling through documents. Magic Mouse 2 is ready to go right out of the box and pairs automatically with your Mac."
     <br>
      Very sensitive item.
     <br>
  </p>
  <h6 class="NoBottomMargin">specification</h6>
  <ul>
    <li>Magic is in the multi-touch</li>
    <li>One or two, left or right</li>
    <li>Laser tracking engine</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: My text is nither in P nor in div.. it is a sibling to "NoBotomMargin" class.

Comment: @Bam - My suggestion is to put it into a sematically correct html element (such as a 'p' or even a blockquote) since having it as naked text within the div is neither good code structure nor easily targetted for CSS / javascript. Rather than trying to create a bad html structure - take the time to improve it and the targetting will become easy. And also - it is very rare to ever need a h6 - are you sure that you are using the h's correctly. and they certainly are not used for spacing / styling purposes.

Comment: Thanks @gavgrif, but I'm writing this HTML, rather I wanted to extract some value from a supplier where I do not have any control to modify their code :).

Answer (score 0):

You can do with nextSibling.

```js
console.log($($('.NoBottomMargin')[0].nextSibling).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderFull_productInfoTabUC_divOverview">
<p>.text 1</p>
<p>.text 2</p>
<p>.text 3</p>
<p>.text 4</p>
<h6 class="NoBottomMargin"></h6>
"Featuring impressive design, Magic Mouse 2 is completely rechargeable, so you'll eliminate the use of traditional batteries. It's lighter, has fewer moving parts thanks to its built-in battery and continuous bottom shell, and has an optimized foot design - all helping Magic Mouse 2 track easier and move with less resistance across your desk. And the multi-touch surface allows you to perform simple gestures such as swiping between web pages and scrolling through documents. Magic Mouse 2 is ready to go right out of the box and pairs automatically with your Mac."
<br>
Very sensitive item.
<br>
<h6 class="NoBottomMargin">specifivation</h6>
<ul>
<li>Magic is in the multi-touch</li>
<li>One or two, left or right</li>
<li>Laser tracking engine</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got answer for this:

```
if($("[id$='divOverview'] .NoBottomMargin").length){
        $("[id$='divOverview'] .NoBottomMargin").eq(0).nextUntil('.NoBottomMargin').each(function(){
            detail.description += "\n" + $(this)[0].previousSibling.nodeValue;
        });
    }
```